# Getting ids from checkboxes in simple form to update in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, checkbox, simple-form, join

I have a Users table and an Activities table and a UsersActivities join table. Activities resources are nested under Users resources. I have checkboxes so that a User can choose preferred Activities. The way I've saved values in the past has been using form_for but I'd like to do this with simple_form. Any ideas? The code below is how I've done it in the past.

```
<% if !@categories.nil? %>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <%= check_box_tag("journal_entry[category_ids][]", category.id, @journal_entry.categories.include?(category))%>
      <%= category.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with making activities avail in the users controller

```
 <%= simple_form_for current_user do |f| %>
   <%= f.association :activities, as: :check_boxes,collection: Activity.all %>
   <%= f.submit 'Save Preferred Activities' %>
```

In Users controller

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, activity_ids: [])
end
```